# How to uninstall protractor from ubuntu?

Tags: npm, protractor

I used

```
sudo npm uninstall protractor
```

but it gives an warning like this:

[image]

Comment: Warnings shouldn't matter. Check if you still have protractor installed in your system. After you uninstall it, protractor command shouldn't be available from your command line/terminal. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if protractor is installed:

```
protractor -v
```

If so, this should work:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g protractor
```